# adding new module to SuiteCRM

Tags: php, module, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm trying to create a new Module pragmatically, but the `metadata` is not being called or showed , here how am doing it :

in `CRM/Modules/` I added `Vendors` folder inside of it  I added the follwoing folders :

`metadata` , `views` folders

in `views` => `view.list.php`

```
class VendorsViewList extends SugarView
{

}
```

and in `metadata` =>
`listviewdefs.php`

```
$listViewDefs['Vendors'] = array(
    'NAME' => array(
        'width'   => '30',
        'label'   => 'LBL_LIST_OPPORTUNITY_NAME',
        'link'    => true,
        'default' => true),
    'SALES_STAGE' => array(
        'width'   => '10',
        'label'   => 'LBL_LIST_SALES_STAGE',
        'default' => true),
    'AMOUNT_USDOLLAR' => array(
        'width'   => '10',
        'label'   => 'LBL_LIST_AMOUNT_USDOLLAR',
        'align'   => 'right',
        'default' => true,
        'currency_format' => true,
    ),
    'OPPORTUNITY_TYPE' => array(
        'width' => '15',
        'label' => 'LBL_TYPE'),
    'LEAD_SOURCE' => array(
        'width' => '15',
        'label' => 'LBL_LEAD_SOURCE'),
    'NEXT_STEP' => array(
        'width' => '10',
        'label' => 'LBL_NEXT_STEP'),
    'PROBABILITY' => array(
        'width' => '10',
        'label' => 'LBL_PROBABILITY'),
    'DATE_CLOSED' => array(
        'width' => '10',
        'label' => 'LBL_LIST_DATE_CLOSED',
        'default' => true),
    'CREATED_BY_NAME' => array(
        'width' => '10',
        'label' => 'LBL_CREATED'),
    'ASSIGNED_USER_NAME' => array(
        'width' => '5',
        'label' => 'LBL_LIST_ASSIGNED_USER',
        'module' => 'Employees',
        'id' => 'ASSIGNED_USER_ID',
        'default' => true),
    'MODIFIED_BY_NAME' => array(
        'width' => '5',
        'label' => 'LBL_MODIFIED'),
    'DATE_ENTERED' => array(
        'width' => '10',
        'label' => 'LBL_DATE_ENTERED',
        'default' => true)
);
```

and in `metafiles.php`

```
 $metafiles['Vendors'] = array(

    'listviewdefs'    =>    'modules/Vendors/metadata/listviewdefs.php',


 );
```

and in the main module folder I have the controller :
`Vendor.php`

require_once('include/MVC/Controller/SugarController.php');

```
class Vendors extends SugarController
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

I can't see what am missing here , it's calling the `controller` and the `view` , but not the `metadata`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use module builder to create modules. If you select publish, module builder will give a zip file with the minimum needed to get started.

You can then customise the module from there.

Module builder sets up quite a lot for you. It:

- registering the module in include/modules.php
- creating the SugarBean (Model)
- creating the database vardefs
- creating metadata (views)
- creating language files.
- And so on...

Also

The layout in the SugarModules of a package matches the layout of the CRM.

If you are editing a module in SuiteCRM. Remember that you must run a repair and rebuild to clear out any cached files.